# How to mark x pivot SQL server by Month In year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table event which  has 3 columns

```
tblEvent (EventID,FromDate, ToDate)
```

with sample data below

```
EventID   FromDate    ToDate
Event1    2015-1-1    2015-2-15
Event2    2015-1-3    2015-4-15
```

I want to list all events by year of months calendar as below

```
         Jan Feb  Mar   Apr     May....    Dec

Event 1  x   x

Event 2      x    x
```

If a day between `FromDate` and `ToDate` is exists in month, display `'x'`, else display `null`.

Comment: If you have a record dated 2014 and 2015, how would the columns look like?

Comment: I just only want to display in 1 year. However if you can display from month of old year to month of another year is OK.

Comment: Event2 has date between jan to april why in result Feb and Mar is marked

Comment: sorry, sample I made was a mistake, but the second row data display will be Jan(x), Feb(x),Mar(x), Apr(x)